# find row in data frame with closest match in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R consisting of say, 5 rows(records) each of 3 attributes. Now given a new record of the same 20 attributes, what is the best way to find which of the 10 rows, this new row is most similar to, in terms of it's contents(values) ?

*Existing data*

```
Age Occupation Nationality,
23  Builder    German,
29  Worker     British,
45  Contractor Vietnamese,
24  Engineer   German,
28  Doctor     Indian,
```

*New data*

```
23  Doctor German
```

*Expected output*

```
23  Builder    German
```

I would like to return row 1, ie, the above row, since two attributes match

Comment: Are you concerned about ties?  How should those be handled?

Comment: could you provide some sample data?

Comment: @cdeterman ties? I'm sorry, do you mean how closely each row in the existing data is tied with the test data? I'm not sure how those should be handled, Jaccard similarity maybe?

Comment: @Achak : Please hold on for a couple of minutes, I am generating some sample data.

Comment: @IAMTubby, what cdetermann means is, consider if the new data was `26  Doctor German` which means that it would have 1 match for both row 1 _and_ row 5 and row 4 in fact. Which would be the expected result in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stringdist` from `stringdist` with `method=jaccard`.  By using `Map`, we are comparing the columns of `df` with corresponding `elements` of list `newdata`. i.e. `Age` column from `df` is used for `stringdist` comparison with `23`, `Occupation` with `Doctor` and so on...  After we apply the `stringdist` function, we get numeric values with length equal to `nrow(df)` for each list element.  The corresponding values are added (`+`) using `Reduce` and then we look for the value which is the `minimum` with `which.min` (output will be a logical index).  This index is used for subsetting the `df`.

```
library(stringdist)
df[which.min(Reduce(`+`,Map(stringdist,df, newdata,
                                 method='jaccard'))),]

#  Age Occupation Nationality
#1  23    Builder      German
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(Age = c(23, 29, 45, 24, 28), Occupation = c("Builder", 
"Worker", "Contractor", "Engineer", "Doctor"), Nationality = c("German", 
"British", "Vietnamese", "German", "Indian")), .Names = c("Age", 
"Occupation", "Nationality"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

newdata <- list(23,"Doctor","German")
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to understand what's happening. Map(stringdist,method='jaccard',df, newdata)) gave me $jaccard and two $<NA>. The Reduce function reduced it to a set of numbers. Could you please tell me a bit about these two functions?

Comment: @IAMTubby I will update the post with some explanation.  You can probably get rid of `$<NA` by `USE.NAMES=FALSE` within the `Map`

Comment: @arunk, thanks for the explanation, but I still haven't got a couple of things. 1.I understand that the three rows I get here are probably the match for each column of values. But why are they specified as NA for the 2nd and 3rd column. Map output - 
[1] 0.0000000 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.6666667

$<NA>
[1] 0.9090909 0.7500000 0.5000000 0.9000000 0.0000000

$<NA>
[1] 0.0000000 0.9090909 0.6000000 0.0000000 0.7777778

And second, how does newdata know what column it's supposed to compare against(here Age)? Is it possible to compare Age against another column, ID, say?

Thanks once again

Comment: @IAMTubby 1. You can change the `Map` function to `Map(function(x,y) stringdist(x,y, method='jaccard'), df, newdata)` and then the `column names` appear as `list` names.  Here, the results are the same.  I am not really sure why that happened.  2) `df` is a dataframe, which is also a list with the columns as `list` elements.  Suppose we are comparing a vector of 3 elements or a list of 3 elements, the corresponding elements get compared here.  You can change the order of `newdata` and compare say `Age` column of `df` to `Occupation` from `newdata`

Comment: @IAMTubby Just change the position of `method=jaccard` as the last entry and you won't have the `$NA` Please check the update.

Comment: ,I understand both 1) and 2). Thank you so much, I shall go with df[which.min(Reduce(`+`,Map(function(x,y) stringdist(x,y, method='jaccard'), df, newdata))),]

Answer (score 2):

```
df<-data.frame(Age=c(23,29,45,24,28),Occupation=c("Builder","Worker","Contractor","Engineer","Doctor"),Nationality=c("German","British","Vietnamese","German","Indian"),stringsAsFactors=F)

newdata<-c(23,"Doctor","German")


df[which.max(apply(df,1,function(vec,dat){sum(vec==dat)},newdata)),]

  Age Occupation Nationality
1  23    Builder      German
```

In case of ties, you can have all better matches with :

```
detmatches<-apply(df,1,function(vec,dat){sum(vec==dat)},newdata)
df[which(detmatches==max(detmatches)),]
```

Comment: Just to note, by using `which.max` you make the assumption that they want `ties.method == "first"`.

Comment: @beginneR, yes you're right, but as the OP didn't yet precise how to handle ties... but I'll add an option to return all better matches. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: @CathG ,The apply function gave me an array like 2 0 0 1 1. Could you tell me what's happening here?

Comment: @IAMTubby, that is exactly what it is supposed to give you : it counts the number of equal items between each row of df and the newdata. So 2 is the number of equal items between 1st row of df and newdata, 0 is the number of equal items between 2nd row of df and newdata, and so on. Then you'll search for the row(s) that correspond(s) to maximum of equal items